# Axios not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've installed axios with npm, but for some reason it's not compiling.

A snippet of my package.json file:

```
    "aws4": {
      "version": "1.9.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/aws4/-/aws4-1.9.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-wMHVg2EOHaMRxbzgFJ9gtjOOCrI80OHLG14rxi28XwOW8ux6IiEbRCGGGqCtdAIg4FQCbW20k9RsT4y3gJlFug=="
    },
    "axios": {
      "version": "0.19.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.19.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-fjgm5MvRHLhx+osE2xoekY70AhARk3a6hkN+3Io1jc00jtquGvxYlKlsFUhmUET0V5te6CcZI7lcv2Ym61mjHA==",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "1.5.10"
      },
      "dependencies": {
```

A snippet of my package.lock.json file:

```
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
```

Where I use axios:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Search from './components/search.js';
import axios from 'axois';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    s: "", //search query. empty string is default entry
    results: [], //initially, no results, so empty array
    selected: {}, //the actual element clicked up out of the presented results
  })

  const apiurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=af1c6093";
  
  const search = (e) => {
    if(e.key === "Enter") {
      axios(apiurl + "&s=" + state.s).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Let me know if you would like me to provide any more context/code.

Update:
-- I fixed the embarrassing mistake of writing 'axois' instead of 'axios', but I currently have a new issue -- element type is invalid, check render method of App. I found another post on this website that and am currently trying to troubleshoot. Perhaps an import/export issue? Nonetheless, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import axios from 'axois';` that should be `'axios'` not `'axois'`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your import. `axois` should be `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

instead of

```
import axios from 'axois';
```